# Unresolved External Symbol (LNK2001) when calling function with a function pointer as an argument

Tags: c++, templates, cuda

I created a class, `ProcessQueue`:

```
//ProcessQueue.h
template<class T>
class ProcessQueue{
public:
    void addTask(T param);
    void clearQueue();
    void addSetup(void (*setup)());
    void addProcess(void (*process)(T));
    void addCleanup(void (*cleanup)());
    void setup();
    void finish();
private:
    //Some private fields and functions that aren't relevant
}
```

`addSetup` and `addCleanup` add functions that are performed when `setup` and `finish` are called (The function pointers are then stored in a `vector`, but that shouldn't matter). `addProcess` should accept a `void` function that inputs a variable of type `T`, and `addTask` adds a variable of type `T` to a processing queue.

When `clearQueue` is called, the class iterates over each `T` that has been added and calls the various "process" functions that have been added to the `ProcessQueue`.

In another file (`kernel.cu`), I use a ProcessQueue to process the results of a computation:

(Note that this is part of the `host` code of the `cu` file, so it is regular C++. `runRecord` is simply a c-style `struct`)

```
//kernel.cu
ProcessQueue<runRecord> queue;

#ifdef PRINTTOFILE
queue.addSetup(setupPrintToFile);
queue.addProcess(processPrintToFile);
queue.addCleanup(cleanupPrintToFile);
#endif

#ifdef PRINTRESULTS
queue.addProcess(printRecord);
#endif

queue.setup();

//Do some computation
//Add the results to the ProcessQueue

queue.clearQueue();
queue.finish();
```

Some other function declarations that may be relevant:

```
//Various .h files
void setupPrintToFile();
void processPrintToFile(runRecord r);
void cleanupPrintToFile();
void printRecord(runRecord rec);
```

When I compile this, I get a few error messages:

```
1>kernel.cu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall ProcessQueue<struct runRecord>::addTask(struct runRecord)" (?addTask@?$ProcessQueue@UrunRecord@@@@QAEXUrunRecord@@@Z)
1>kernel.cu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall ProcessQueue<struct runRecord>::clearQueue(void)" (?clearQueue@?$ProcessQueue@UrunRecord@@@@QAEXXZ)
1>kernel.cu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall ProcessQueue<struct runRecord>::addSetup(void (__cdecl*)(void))" (?addSetup@?$ProcessQueue@UrunRecord@@@@QAEXP6AXXZ@Z)
1>kernel.cu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall ProcessQueue<struct runRecord>::addProcess(void (__cdecl*)(struct runRecord))" (?addProcess@?$ProcessQueue@UrunRecord@@@@QAEXP6AXUrunRecord@@@Z@Z)
1>kernel.cu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall ProcessQueue<struct runRecord>::addCleanup(void (__cdecl*)(void))" (?addCleanup@?$ProcessQueue@UrunRecord@@@@QAEXP6AXXZ@Z)
1>kernel.cu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall ProcessQueue<struct runRecord>::finish(void)" (?finish@?$ProcessQueue@UrunRecord@@@@QAEXXZ)
fatal error LNK1120: 6 unresolved externals
```

I'm not too sure where the problem is. I've tried changing the template and function declarations, but it doesn't seem to help.

The compiler is nvcc v7.5.

Comment: Is you class split between a header and cpp file?

Comment: Yes, they are all split. I'll add the locations of all of them in an edit

Comment: You do *link* with the object file generated from the source file where all those functions are implemented? You *do* have an object file? You *do* have a source file? And it's actually in the *project* (and not only on the disk)? And the source file *do* have the definitions (implementations) of those functions?

Comment: You're showing where all of your functions are declared, in a header file.  But you're not showing their definitions.  You need to implement the functions, not just declare them.

Comment: Yes, they are implemented

Comment: So I need to put the implementation of `ProcessQueue` in the header file? (Or include the .cpp at the end of the header?)

Comment: Templates can only be in header files.

Comment: Nvcc isn't a compiler, and it isn't compiling any of the code in this question. What version of visual studio address you using?

Comment: Writing `#include "ProcessQueue.cpp"` at the end of `ProcessQueue.h` solved the problem.